# Since vptr is inherited in derived class, how it point to its own vtable?

Tags: c++

I googled many explanation and they said vptr is only declared on Base class, the Derived class only inherit the vptr and construct during constructing the object. And vptr point to its own vtable(NOT Base::vtable)

So to my understanding, in this model, we only have Base::vptr, but we have two different vtable (Base & Derived). How one vptr manage two vtables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The virtual table pointer is just like any other member variable, it's just hidden from the program and the code (so it can't be accessed directly).

And as any other normal member variable, an instance of the base class will have its own distinct copy of vtable pointer. And an instance of a child class will have its own distinct copy of it. And the child class can then modify the variable as it pleases.

Comment: That make sense. So object of Base and object of Derived is actually 'isolated'. By 'isolated' I mean they each has its own copy of vptr point to each own vtable, just vptr declaration is only happen on Base(otherwise I think would be duplicated to have two vptr in Derived one).

Answer (score 2):

Not all object has a vptr, only object whose class has virtual keyword has a vptr in the top of the object's memory. For c++'s RTTi, vptr is used to recognizing the class of an object. One object only have ONE vptr or not, and it point to the vtable of the really class.

for example:

```
class A {}; // object create by this class doesn't have vptr
class B { virtual void x();};// object create by this class has a vptr point to class B's vtable
class C: public B{ virtual void x();};// object create by this class has a vptr point to class C's vtable

// suppose the address of B's vtable is 0x0010
// suppose the address of C's vtable is 0x0018
B* obj = new C();
// objhas one vptr and the vptr is 0x0018
obj->x(); // so this call use the vtable of class C to call C::x()
```

Comment: @Melebius  The conclusion is that one class only have one vtable not two.